# regex match first label: on line ignoring spaces

Tags: regex

I try to find first word on line like `label:` or `start:` ignoring spaces.
Labels are first words on line followed by colon (:)

```
Label1:texttext
    Label2: teeext
text NONLABEL:
```

My code (Qt C) is:

```
QRegExp("^\\s*([A-Za-z0-9]+:)");
```

but this is capturing also spaces.

Please help.
Florin.

Comment: try this regex https://regex101.com/r/qF7bQ9/1

Comment: @Kamran the regex is fine..OP just wants to ignore spaces if its there before the word

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But this solution `^(\S[A-Za-z0-9]+:)`  is not capturing `Label2:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access first capturing group

```
QRegExp grp("^\\s*([A-Za-z0-9]+:)");
QString captured = grp.cap(1);
                   <-------->
              First capturing group
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. There may be a solution involving (? =) Lookahead? I ask because the rule above is one of many rules that I apply. And if you use `QString captured = grp.cap(1);` then I have to use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
QRegExp("(?:^\\s*)([a-z0-9]+):", Qt::CaseInsensitive);
```

Thank you all for your help!